# How do I order 'subdata' in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase dataset with the following structure:

```
 coloursets
  - default
    - key
    - name
    - colours
      - black
        - key
        - name
        - hex code
        - order
      - white
        - key
        - name
        - hex code
        - order
```

'Order' is just a number. When I retrieve it from the database, I want to be able to get the colours in a particular order, specified by the 'order' field. Eg to get black and then white, I'll give 'black' the order '1', and 'white' the order '2'.

How do I use this to retrieve the data in order? Or is there a better way to do it?

I'm currently using this to retrieve it:

```
DatabaseReference mColourSetReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                    .child("coloursets").child(this.key);
mColourSetReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
```

but there's no way to specify the order to retrieve the colours.  It seems to default to reverse order, so currently it's getting white first, and then black.

I'm more used to MySQL, so can't get my head around this, and I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

### Edit

Here's a screenshot of the relevant parts of the database:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To order, try this:

```
DatabaseReference mColourSetReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("coloursets").child("colours");
Query queries=mColourSetReference.orderByChild("order");
```

> `public Query orderByChild (String path)`
>
> Create a query in which child nodes are ordered by the values of the specified path.

more info here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#orderByChild(java.lang.String)

Comment: That's giving me an "Incompatible types" error - it's returning a Query instead of a DatabaseReference...

Comment: Trying it at the moment - I only saw your edit there when I posted my own edit!

Comment: Still not working - that seems to just retrieve the colours.  I need the entire colourset.  So I think the "this.key" should still be in there somewhere.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the database

Comment: Have added a screenshot - I cut out a few extra bits and pieces just to make it clearer (each colour has a bit more info than what's shown, for instance).

Comment: change it to this: `DatabaseReference mColourSetReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("coloursets").child("default").child("colours"); Query queries=mColourSetReference.orderByChild("order");` this should give you black object then white object

Comment: That works for just the colours, but I need to retrieve the whole colourset entry. So I need to retrieve the colourset name and description, and the colours as well, but with the colours sorted.  Does that make sense? Thanks for your help; I really appreciate it.

Comment: try this: `DatabaseReference mColourSetReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("coloursets"); Query queries=mColourSetReference.orderByChild("default/black/colours/order");` and then try and get description,key and name in valueventlistener

Comment: Nope, still getting them in the wrong order. It seems like I should do something like orderByChild("colours/*/order"), but there doesn't seem to be a wildcard option. Also it feels like I should be specifying that it's the colours I want to sort, rather than mColourSetReference - the above looks like it would try to sort mColourSetReference.

Comment: `mColourSetReference` is a snapshot at coloursets but then u order this `orderByChild("default/black/colours/order");` and yes u do specify the color which is black, this will let you retrieve description and key after adding a valueeventlistener and iterating inside `default`, but the best thing is to change the database structure

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll change the db structure, that might be easiest. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: check this also might help: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html, no problem!